# Number Format Exception occuring, try catch throwing exception?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am having an issue with this part of the method. The program is supposed to pass arguments, which in my binaryToDecimal method it does just fine. But everytime this method, the decimalToBinary attempts to pass the value of 5 to binary, it tells me the Number Format Exception occurs and it doesn't do the calculation. Anything I could try to avoid this from happening?

```
public static String decimalToBinary(String decimalString) {
    int decimal = 0;


    try {
        decimal = Integer.parseInt("decimalString");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Number format exception occured"); 
        }

    String answer = "";

    while(decimal > 0) {
        answer = decimal%2+answer;

    }
    return answer; 
}
```

Comment: Remove the `" "` around `decimalString` inside the call to `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: *FYI:* Once the code gets past that, the `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: *Curious:* Why not use [`Integer.toString(decimal, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-)?

Comment: `decimal = Integer.parseInt(decimalString)` instead of `decimal = Integer.parseInt("decimalString")`

Comment: What do you mean by writing 'try/catch *not* throwing an exception' in your title, and writing in the body of your question that it does? Please check your posts for consistency.

Comment: Your title says, your program isn't throwing an exception, your question description says otherwise. Highly think as @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica said, remove quotes from `decimalString` and pass the variable to `Integer.parseInt`and not pass in a `String` of value `decimalString`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in here `decimal = Integer.parseInt("decimalString");`

you should used your parameter `decimalString`

instead of this `decimal = Integer.parseInt("decimalString");`

try using this `decimal = Integer.parseInt(decimalString);`